# Routing Lib for PHP7

Tags: php, routes, autoload, php-7

I need to use a routing plugin for php and I decided to use nikic/FastRoute [https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute]. But, because of my limited knowledge to php, I still cannot use it successfully.

Here is my code.

```
require_once 'FastRoute/src/functions.php';
# create a stack of actions

$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/', 'get_all_users_handler');
    // {id} must be a number (\d+)
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/contract-management', 'get_user_handler');
    // The /{title} suffix is optional
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/articles/{id:\d+}[/{title}]', 'get_article_handler');
});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        // ... call $handler with $vars
        break;
}

function get_user_handler(){
    print_r("here");
}

function get_article_handler(){
    print_r("article handler");
}
```

I just changed require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; to require_once 'FastRoute/src/functions.php'; from the example code. But the below error shown.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FastRoute\RouteCollector' not found in C:\wamp\www\testproj\includes\FastRoute\src\functions.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\testproj\includes\routing.php(13): FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(Object(Closure)) #1 C:\wamp\www\testproj\index.php(9): require_once('C:\wamp\www\testp...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\testproj\includes\FastRoute\src\functions.php on line 21

I think I did something wrong with setting up. But I still cannot find a better sample for the beginners. So, please point me where did I do wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your already mentioned your error: "I  just changed require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; to require_once 'FastRoute/src/functions.php'; from the example code." Search for PHP composer and autoload.

Comment: Thanks Olaf Dietsche. I didn't realize that this composer or autoload have that much effect. But I still have a question. Can't I just not install this PHP composer to use this kind of libraries? Is there custom way to load the library without installing composer? I do not want to install this on every live servers and my local one just to use this one lib. Or do I  have no choice?

Comment: When you change a program somehow, and then it stops working, just revert your change and see, if it solves the problem. Then you can look at the relevant code and try to understand how the code (or its absence) influences your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [PHP autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Your problem lies in removing the line

```
require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This PHP script installs an autoloader, which automatically loads the necessary PHP script files, when some needed PHP class is unknown.

If you don't want this autoloader for some reason, you have to load the needed classes through some other way. Usually this is done by adding lines like *in every PHP script*

```
require 'FastRoute/RouteCollector.php';
require 'FastRoute/Dispatcher.php';
...
```

So, most of the time you do want this autoloader, because it makes life much easier and the code shorter.